# How to allow writing to a file on the server ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, permissions

So I have file that is in folder in website folder structure.
I use it to log errors.

It works when ran from Visual Studio.

I understand the problem. I need to set permissions on inetpub.
But for what user ? and how?

I tried adding some IIS user but it still can not write to the file.

So I am using ASP.net
Framework 3.5 SP1
Server is Windows Server 2003 enterprise edition SP2

How should I set up permissions so write would work?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to give the Network Service account modify rights.
Right click on the folder, choose properties, go to the Security tab and add the Network Service account if it's not there.  If it is listed, ensure it had "Modify" checked.

Answer (score 0):

which users have you granted write access on the folder? I believe you may need to give write access to the user that runs ASP NET user.

Answer (score 0):

ONe solution is to give the ASP.NET user writes on the folder you will be accessing via the site.
Else you can impersonate an admin to run the website. This can be done via inetmgr.